# Получить содержимое li при помощи xpath

Tags: c#, html, xpath

Есть следующий кусок html

```
   <div class="full-story__top__info-fields">
                <ul>

                    <li itemprop="copyrightYear"><span>Год:</span> 2019</li>
                    <li itemprop="contributor"><span>Страна:</span> США</li> 
                    <li><span>Перевод:</span> Дубляж</li>
                    <li><span>Жанр:</span> фэнтези, боевик, приключения</li>
                    <li><span>Качество:</span> TS</li>
                    <li itemprop="director"><span>Режиссерский состав:</span> Нил Маршалл</li>
                    <li itemprop="actor"><span>В Ролях:</span> Дэвид Харбор, Иэн МакШейн, Милла Йовович, Марк Стэнли, Брин Глисон, Надя Керанова, Мария Тепавичарова, Ана Тобакова, Пенелопа Митчелл, Терри Рендал</li>

                    <li><span>Время:</span> 01:49:22</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Необходимо получить значения, что идут после "перевод:", "жанр:" и "качество:".
Пытался так:

```
//div[@class='full-story__top__info-fields' and contains(li, 'Перевод')]
```

Но возвращает Null.

Comment: Вы в курсе, что вы можете просто в хроме зайти на сайт, нажать F12, выбрать нужный вам элемент и [скопировать его XPath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ha5w.png)?

Comment: `//div/ul/li/text()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вам обязателен xpath? Для парсинга DOM-объектов HTML гораздо проще использовать [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/), имхо.

UPD:

Попробуйте брать не SelectSingleNode, а все элементы списка, например так:

```
IEnumerable<string> liData = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//div[@class='full-story__top__info-fields']/ul/li").Select(li => li.OuterHtml);
```

А затем, зная ваш html, брать нужные вам поля из коллекции.

Comment: Так я hap-ом и делаю это) Но там ведь надо как-то добраться до нужного элемента, а в SelectSingleNode, насколько я знаю, можно только xpath-выражение указать, чтобы получить нужное значение.

Comment: @АндрейФедоров, обновил ответ.